# Store Value of Jquery Selector Call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using a jquery selector function, the factory function: $() to be precise, is there a way to collect the status of its execution? i.e. Is there a way to translate the status of its execution to a 'storeable' value e.g. true, false, null, etc.?

Code Example:

```
var form_submitted_successfully = $("#formsubmit").submit();
```

The above code snippet returns an Object.

Comment: You couldn't call the `submit` method if the `$()` function didn't return a value *with* a method called `submit` ;)

Comment: It seems you are conflating multiple things here: Yes, you can store the return value of `$("#formsubmit")` in a variable. No, `.submit()` doesn't return the status of submission (instead it returns the jQuery object it was called on). Also form submission always succeeds in the sense that the browser will load the page the form links to (whether the loading works or not is a separate question).  At that point the previous page's JavaScript is not running anymore. What is your *actual* question? It seems you are asking for one thing but actually want something else.

Comment: When you submit a form, the page is reloaded and scripts in the current page stop. If you want to submit without reloading you need to learn about AJAX.

Comment: @Felix Kling, I understand that the page will reload once a form is successfully submitted. If the form is not successfully submitted though, does the .submit function return a value nevertheless? can an error message be displayed based on said function call?

Comment: *"I understand that the page will reload once a form is successfully submitted"* Maybe we have to clarify what "submitted" and "successfully" means in this context. My assumption is that the browser gets all the form data (without problem) and sends that data to the target page by loading said page. That is the submission part. At the point the previous page doesn't exist anymore, so there is nothing to notify when the server wasn't able to handle the request, only the user. What do you mean by these terms?